# Настройка маршрутов Django

Tags: python, django

Ищу решение следующего вопроса:
Сайт должен иметь подобные маршруты:

```
shop.ru/all/
shop.ru/all/chasy-i-ukrasheniya/
shop.ru/all/chasy-i-ukrasheniya/bizhuteriya/
shop.ru/all/chasy-i-ukrasheniya/bizhuteriya/braslety
```

Каждый маршрут будет возвращать полноценный контент
Но прописывать для каждого из них отдельные маршруты в urls.py не будет ли непрактично? Нельзя всё это дело как-либо автоматизировать?

Comment: `/all/<path:blablabla>`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Comment: К сожалению, я не смог разобраться в инструкции... Не могли бы вы на примере показать использование данного метода, пожалуйста?